# A text editor driven file renamer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-system

I wrote the following Ruby script several years ago and have been using it often ever since.

It opens a text editor with the list of files in current directory. You can then edit the file names as text. Once you save and exit the files are renamed.

The `renamer` allowed me to maintain spreadsheet-like file names thanks to the powerful column editing capabilities of vi (emacs also has those).

Here is how one such directory looks:

[image]

I would like to use it as an example for a Ruby workshop. Could you please suggest best-practice and design pattern improvements?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

RM = '/bin/rm'
MV = '/bin/mv'

from = Dir.entries('.').sort; from.delete('.'); from.delete('..')
from.sort!

from.delete_if {|i| i =~ /^\./} # Hidden files

tmp = "/tmp/renamer.#{Time.now.to_i}.#{(rand * 1000).to_i}"

File.open(tmp, 'w') do |f|
  from.each {|i| f.puts i}
end

ENV['EDITOR'] = 'vi' if ENV['EDITOR'].nil?
system("#{ENV['EDITOR']} #{tmp}")

to = File.open(tmp) {|f| f.readlines.collect{|l| l.chomp}}
`#{RM} #{tmp}`

if to.size != from.size
  STDERR.puts "renamer: ERROR: number of lines changed"
  exit(1)
end

from.each_with_index do |f, i|
  puts `#{MV} -v --interactive "#{f}" "#{to[i]}"` unless f == to[i]
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RM = '/bin/rm'
MV = '/bin/mv'
```

In general it's preferable to use the [`FileUtils` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/index.html) rather than relying on shell utilities. Though in this particular case, you might want to stick at least with `mv` since the `FileUtils.mv` method does not have an `:interactive` option.

---

```
tmp = "/tmp/renamer.#{Time.now.to_i}.#{(rand * 1000).to_i}"
```

Ruby has a [`Tempfile` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/index.html) which can generate a unique temporary file more reliably than this. You should use it.

---

```
from.each {|i| f.puts i}
```

Calling `puts` on an array will `puts` each line individually, so the above can just be shortened to `f.puts from`.

---

```
ENV['EDITOR'] = 'vi' if ENV['EDITOR'].nil?
```

Can be shortened to `ENV['EDITOR'] ||= 'vi'`. Though what you have isn't particularly verbose either, so it doesn't really matter much which one you choose.

---

```
system("#{ENV['EDITOR']} #{tmp}")
```

Use `system(ENV[EDITOR], tmp)` instead. This way you get rid of the string interpolation and the code still works if either `ENV['EDITOR']` or `tmp` should contain a space or other shell meta-character (not that they're particularly likely to, but it's a good idea to use the multiple-argument-form of `system` where ever possible).

---

```
to = File.open(tmp) {|f| f.readlines.collect{|l| l.chomp}}
```

Usually this could be replaced with `to = File.readlines(tmp).collect {|l| l.chomp}`. However if you follow my suggestion of using `Tempfile`, that won't be an option any more.

---

```
`#{RM} #{tmp}`
```

If you use fileutils, this will just be `FileUtils.rm(tmp)` (or `rm(tmp)` if you include `FileUtils`). If you don't want to use `FileUtils`, you should at least use `system(RM, tmp)` for the same reasons as above.

However if you use `Tempfile`, which you should, this becomes redundant anyway.

---

```
from.each_with_index do |f, i|
  puts `#{MV} -v --interactive "#{f}" "#{to[i]}"` unless f == to[i]
end
```

To iterate over two arrays in parallel, use `zip`:

```
from.zip(to) do |f, t|
  system(MV, "-v", "--interactive", f, t) unless f == t
end
```

Note that here using `system` instead of backticks is especially important since one of the files in `from` or `to` containing spaces is actually somewhat likely.

---

So with all my suggestions, your code should now look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'tempfile'

MV = '/bin/mv'

from = Dir.glob('*').sort

ENV['EDITOR'] ||= 'vi'

to = nil
Tempfile.open("renamer") do |f|
  f.puts from
  f.close
  system(ENV['EDITOR'], f.path)
  f.open
  to = f.readlines.collect {|l| l.chomp}
end

if to.size != from.size
  STDERR.puts "renamer: ERROR: number of lines changed"
  exit(1)
end

from.zip(to) do |f, t|
  system(MV, "-v", "--interactive", f, t) unless f == t
end
```

Comment: Surprisingly, `to = Tempfile.open(...){...; "result"}` does not work. `to` gets nil. Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @Aleksandr: Bah, stupid of me to forget to replace the `tmp`. That `open` does not return the block's result surprises me too (I had not tested it previously). Anyway I've fixed it.

Comment: A very good review of the code and a good look at "idiomatic" Ruby. Well done

Answer (score 5):

Just a couple of things:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

It's possible that on some systems this isn't where ruby lives, it's better to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

---

```
from = Dir.entries('.').sort; from.delete('.'); from.delete('..')
```

Can be written as

```
from = Dir.entries('.').sort - ['.', '..']
```

Which is more succinct and eliminates having three statements on one line (which you shouldn't do).

Or you could eliminate hidden files and . / .. in one go with:

```
from = Dir.entries(.).select do |filename|
    filename[0].chr != '.'
end
```

*Edit:*

```
from = Dir.glob("*").sort
```

Is definitely the best solution.

Comment: Using the `/usr/bin/env` trick is especially important for people who've compiled Ruby themselves or (like me, and a lot of the Ruby world) are using RVM.

Comment: I just replaced the whole thing with `from = Dir.glob("*").sort`